# Sticky footer doesn't stop where requested, bounces at bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using scrollToFixed to have a footer stick to the bottom of the page until it hits the actual footer and then it's supposed to stop. However, it scrolls to the bottom of the page and past the footer and the snaps to the top of the footer. Any ideas why this bug is happening? Here's a link to the actual site: http://client.analog.la/ret5/

```
jQuery('#scroller').scrollToFixed({
    bottom: 0,
    limit:  function() { 
    var limit = 0;
        if (jQuery(window).height() > jQuery('#page').height()) {
            jQuery('#colophon').css({'position':'fixed','bottom':'0'});
            jQuery('#scroller').css({'position':'fixed','bottom':'40px'});
        }else {
             jQuery('#colophon').css({'position':'static'});
             limit = jQuery('#scroller').offset().top + 40;
        } return limit;
        }

});
```

Comment: Please provide the browser information.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 25.0.1364.152, but it needs to work in most browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should substract the height of the footer

On my browser it was fine...for the #scroller but the content was all the way at the bottom. Wich version/browser are you using.

Comment: This is working for the limit, but now the whole thing is flickering when the page scrolls. What's causing that?

Comment: I'm using chrome 25.0.1364.152. It's not working at all on Firefox, no idea why not.

Comment: Where do you write the code to scollTo because it seems a lot of unnessesary iterations are causing it to flicker.

Comment: It's just in a `$(document).ready()` in a `<script>` tag in `footer.php`.

Comment: The problem comes from the limit function being called each time, i believe there is a much simpler CSS only way to keep the little footer at the bottom.  Was there a reason why you wanted it to be moved using jquery.

Comment: Yes. It needs to be jQuery because I need it to stop scrolling when it hits the main footer with the content. I have a conditional that positions the whole footer absolute if the window is taller than the page.

Comment: Also, why isn't it working in firefox? It should work in Firefox.

Comment: @elkirkmo Why did you mark this as solved? Sounds like your problem still exists...

Comment: @Swordfish0321 I marked it as solved because it's mostly solved. The original question had to do with the footer scroll stop point and this solution worked for that.